# Find all non-decreasing sequences given lenght and size

Tags: algorithms, backtracking

I'm trying to find a solution for this exercise:

> Give the pseudocode of an algorithm which takes two positive integers
>   n and k and prints all the non-decreasing sequences of length k
>   (1,2,...,n).
>
> For example n=4, k=3:
>
> 111 112 113 114 122 123 124 133 134 144 222 223 224 233 234 244 333
>   334 344 444
>
> the complexity must be O(n S(n,k)) with S(n,k) the number of the
>   sequences to print for n and k.

i think from the complexity required that a backtracking algorithm it's needed  but i could'nt solve it.

i tried something like this:

```
P(n,k,h: prefix length, S: sequence)

      if h == k then
           OUTPUT S
      else
         for i=1 to n do
             if(i>=S[h]) 
                   S[h+1]=i;
                   P(n,k,h+1,S);
```

Comment: Your question still lacks, well, a (specific) *question*. What is the idea of your approach? Why do you think it does (not) work?

Comment: Thanks for answering Raphael, since i edited it is misleading, i only added the code after David's hint. So now i think this works and the question now is if it really does or doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Given the available time complexity, a simple recursive algorithm should work. If you need a sequence of length $k$ from the set $\{m, \dots, n\}$ you either include $m$ or you don't.

Comment: Thanks, so the algorithm i did is correct?  being a backtracking algorith it has O(nS(n)) where S(n) are the generated sequences, am i right?